# Exception compile is raised in SML

Tags: sml

I have written the below code in SML, but I came across with compile errors.

```
fun getTransIndex(t : TRANSACTION, (h::L) : TRANSLIST) : int =
    let val i=0
    in if (h=t) then i 
       else
         if (getTransIndex(t,L)<>~1
         then getTransIndex(t,L)+1
         else ~1
    end

getTransIndex(_,[] )=~1;
```

TRANSACTION is an index with values: 1..3
TRANSLIST is list of TRANSACTION

Function `getTransIndex` takes a transaction identity of
colset TRANSACTION as first parameter and a list of
transactions with colset TRANSLIST as second parameter
and returns the index of transaction's position in the list
(counting from 0). If list does not contains this transaction, then
function returns -1 as result.

So I want to fix the problems. What is the solution?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this:

1) You have a superfluous unmatched left parenthesis in the line

```
if (getTransIndex(t,L)<>~1 then
```

2) SML can't parse the `)<>~1`. You should introduce spaces around `<>`

Putting these two points together, that line should read:

```
if getTransIndex(t,L) <> ~1 then
```

3) The line `getTransIndex(_,[] )=~1;` really makes no sense. `_` isn't a bound value which can be passed to `getTransIndex` and the empty list `[]` is not covered by the only pattern used in the definition `h::L`. You need to either give a definition for `getTransIndex(t,[])` or not pass it the empty list. **On Edit**: As @molbdnilo pointed out, this was probably intended to be the basis case. If so, it is missing the `|` and is also somewhat misplaced since it is more idiomatic to have the case `[]` first.

4) The `let val i = 0 in` is somewhat pointless. Why not use the literal value `0` and get rid of the `let ... in ... end`.

5) `TRANSACTION` and `TRANSLIST` are apparently types. It is standard SML usage to use lower cases for types and reserve upper case for constructors in abstract data types.

Putting this all together (and using `int` as a stand-in for your `TRANSASCTION`) leads to code like:

```
type transaction = int
type translist = int list

fun getTransIndex(_,[]:translist) = ~1
|   getTransIndex(t:transaction,(h::L)) =
    if (h=t) then 
        0 
    else  
        if getTransIndex(t,L) <> ~1 then 
            getTransIndex(t,L)+1
        else ~1;
```

There is no reason to explicitly tell SML that `~1` is an int. On the other hand, `_:transaction` doesn't work as intended since `_` isn't an ordinary identifier, so I moved the type annotation `:transaction` to the line which contains `t`.

Comment: Very thorough feedback. :)

Comment: I think the line `getTransIndex(_,[] )=~1;` is meant to be the definition for the empty list case, but is missing its `|`.

Comment: @molbdnilo You are undoubtedly correct. I am so used to seeing empty list basis cases first in a definition that I read that line as a test case for the function definition above it. I'll edit the answer. Thanks.